# R: plotting lines (SpatialLinesDataFrame) with a different line type according to a nominal attribute

Tags: r, line, plot

**Data**

I have two pairs of lines (SpatialLinesDataframe), 4 overall. The dataset is pasted below:

```
mydata <- new("SpatialLinesDataFrame", data = structure(list(length = c(500.842234293619, 
293.606797749979, 612.066409242344, 629.705729467346), funct = c("t", 
"t", "wcs", "wcs")), row.names = c("1", "2", "11", "21"), class = "data.frame"), 
    lines = list(new("Lines", Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(2667675, 
    2667655, 2667645, 2667655, 2667645, 2667645, 2667655, 2667665, 
    2667675, 2667695, 2667705, 2667705, 2667695, 2667695, 2667705, 
    2667725, 2667735, 2667755, 2667775, 2667795, 2667815, 2667825, 
    2667835, 2667845, 2667855, 2667865, 2667865, 2667855, 6479005, 
    6479015, 6479015, 6479035, 6479055, 6479065, 6479085, 6479095, 
    6479115, 6479125, 6479145, 6479155, 6479175, 6479185, 6479205, 
    6479215, 6479225, 6479235, 6479245, 6479255, 6479265, 6479275, 
    6479285, 6479295, 6479315, 6479335, 6479345, 6479365), .Dim = c(28L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"))))), ID = "1"), new("Lines", 
        Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(2667675, 
        2667685, 2667695, 2667705, 2667725, 2667735, 2667745, 
        2667765, 2667785, 2667795, 2667815, 2667835, 2667855, 
        2667875, 2667895, 2667905, 2667925, 2667935, 6479005, 
        6479005, 6479005, 6479005, 6478995, 6478995, 6479015, 
        6479025, 6479015, 6479015, 6479005, 6478995, 6478985, 
        6478975, 6478965, 6478965, 6478955, 6478955), .Dim = c(18L, 
        2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"))))), ID = "2"), 
        new("Lines", Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(2667675, 
        2667655, 2667655, 2667665, 2667655, 2667675, 2667665, 
        2667655, 2667675, 2667665, 2667655, 2667645, 2667635, 
        2667645, 2667655, 2667665, 2667675, 2667695, 2667705, 
        2667695, 2667685, 2667695, 2667705, 2667725, 2667745, 
        2667755, 2667775, 2667795, 2667815, 2667835, 2667845, 
        2667855, 2667865, 2667865, 2667855, 6479005, 6478995, 
        6479005, 6479015, 6479015, 6479025, 6479025, 6479025, 
        6479035, 6479035, 6479035, 6479035, 6479055, 6479065, 
        6479085, 6479095, 6479115, 6479125, 6479145, 6479165, 
        6479185, 6479205, 6479215, 6479225, 6479235, 6479245, 
        6479255, 6479265, 6479275, 6479285, 6479295, 6479315, 
        6479335, 6479345, 6479365), .Dim = c(35L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("x", "y"))))), ID = "11"), new("Lines", Lines = list(
            new("Line", coords = structure(c(2667675, 2667655, 
            2667655, 2667665, 2667655, 2667675, 2667665, 2667655, 
            2667675, 2667665, 2667655, 2667645, 2667635, 2667645, 
            2667655, 2667675, 2667685, 2667705, 2667725, 2667745, 
            2667755, 2667775, 2667775, 2667785, 2667785, 2667795, 
            2667805, 2667815, 2667815, 2667825, 2667835, 2667845, 
            2667865, 2667885, 2667895, 2667915, 2667925, 2667935, 
            6479005, 6478995, 6479005, 6479015, 6479015, 6479025, 
            6479025, 6479025, 6479035, 6479035, 6479035, 6479035, 
            6479055, 6479065, 6479075, 6479085, 6479105, 6479115, 
            6479125, 6479135, 6479135, 6479145, 6479135, 6479135, 
            6479145, 6479125, 6479105, 6479085, 6479075, 6479055, 
            6479035, 6479025, 6479015, 6479005, 6478995, 6478985, 
            6478975, 6478955), .Dim = c(38L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
                NULL, c("x", "y"))))), ID = "21")), bbox = structure(c(2667635, 
    6478955, 2667935, 6479365), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"))
```

**Goal**

As you can see, to each line is attached a nominal attribute, which is stored under `funct`:

```
> mydata$funct
[1] "t"   "t"   "wcs" "wcs"
```

When plotting those 4 lines, I cannot find a viable way of assigning a different line type (using the `lty` option in r base plotting) according to the nominal variable (e.g., a continuous line for the lines associated to 't', a dashed line to the two associated to 'wcs'). I have made some web search but I could not find anything that can be used in this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line type in R plots is a numeric value, so you need to convert your character column to numbers.

You can do this most easily using `factor`:

```
> mydata$functN = as.numeric(as.factor(mydata$funct))
> as.data.frame(mydata)
     length funct functN
1  500.8422     t      1
2  293.6068     t      1
11 612.0664   wcs      2
21 629.7057   wcs      2
```

those numbers are valid line types, so you can then do:

```
 plot(mydata, lty=mydata$functN)
```

[image]

If you want the solid and dashed lines the other way round then subtract it from 3:

```
plot(mydata, lty=3-mydata$functN)
```

which will transform 2 to 1 and 1 to 2.

Comment: OMG I have been so dumb! Actually I had tried the opposite: as.factor(as.numeric(mydata$funct)), which of course did not work. Thank you.